# How to break from a loop after finding a word

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Hangman and I have 2 problems.

1) The first problem is when the user finds the word, the loop does not stop.

2) I have a variable `attempts` which allows to know the number of attempts. Even if the user finds the letter, the number of attempts decrease.

The word to find is `no`

Here is a demonstration:

1) I enter the letter `n`

```
You have 5 attempts.
--
Enter your letter : n
```

2) I enter the letter `o`

```
The letter is good. 
You have 4 attempts.
n-
Enter your letter : o
```

3) Normally the loop should stop.

```
The letter is good. 
You have 3 attempts.
no
Enter your letter :
```

If you have an idea thank you in advance.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

char letter = 0; 
String[] words = {/*"yes",*/ "no"}; 
String word_random = words[(int) (Math.random() * words.length)]; 
boolean[] word_found = new boolean[word_random.length()];
int attempts = 5;


while(attempts > 0){
  System.out.println("You have " + attempts + " attempts.");
  for(int i=0; i<word_random.length(); i++) {
    if ( word_found[i] ) {
      System.out.print(word_random.charAt(i));
    }
    else {
      System.out.print('-');
    }
  }

  System.out.println("");
  System.out.print("Enter your letter : ");
  letter = input.next().charAt(0);

  for(int i=0; i<word_random.length();i++){
    if(word_random.charAt(i) == letter){
      System.out.println("The letter is good. ");
      word_found[i] = true;
    } 

  }

attempts--;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to change the value of attempts somewhere inside the while loop. As written, the value is always 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing a checking loop or method. Check the solution below.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

char letter = 0; 
String[] words = {/*"yes",*/ "no"}; 
String word_random = words[(int) (Math.random() * words.length)]; 
boolean[] word_found = new boolean[word_random.length()];
int attempts = 5;

while(attempts > 0){
  System.out.println("You have " + attempts + " attempts.");
  for(int i=0; i<word_random.length(); i++) {
    if ( word_found[i] ) {
      System.out.print(word_random.charAt(i));
    }
    else {
      System.out.print('-');
    }
  }

  System.out.println("");
  System.out.print("Enter your letter : ");
  letter = input.next().charAt(0);

  for(int i=0; i<word_random.length();i++){
    if(word_random.charAt(i) == letter){
      System.out.println("The letter is good. ");
      word_found[i] = true;
    } 

  }

  boolean done = true;
  for(boolean b : word_found)
       done = done && b;

   if(done) break;
   else attempts--;

   }
```

Comment: Yes it's OK thank you a lot :-) However, I don't understand `forech` but only the loop `for`

Comment: You can rewrite the for each loop as: `for(int i = 0; i < word_random.length(); i++)` and then in the body put `done = done && word_found[i];`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, my problem is solved thanks to you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I will follow to your solution, not suggest a better one.
Ad 1. Add a check if the array word found contains only true after your first for cycle and if there are only true values in the array, print "you won" and set attempts to 0

Ad 2. Move attempts-- to the else case of your first for cycle OR add attempts++ in the true case of your first for cycle

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    char letter = 0;
    String[] words = { /* "yes", */ "no" };
    String word_random = words[(int) (Math.random() * words.length)];
    boolean[] word_found = new boolean[word_random.length()];
    int attempts = 5;

    while (attempts > 0) {
        System.out.println("You have " + attempts + " attempts.");
        for (int i = 0; i < word_random.length(); i++) {
            if (word_found[i]) {
                System.out.print(word_random.charAt(i));
            } else {
                System.out.print('-');
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter your letter : ");
        letter = input.next().charAt(0);

        boolean match = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < word_random.length(); i++) {
            if (word_random.charAt(i) == letter) {
                System.out.println("The letter is good. ");
                word_found[i] = true;
                match = true;
                if (i == word_found.length - 1) {
                    System.out.println("THE END: attempts: " + attempts);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!match) {
            attempts--;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("THE END");
}
```

I suggest you to modify the last part of your code like I did, and it should work.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. For example if you first enter the letter **o** and the word is **no** the program will exit even if the letter is correct!